# converting date from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have datetime type from DB table.

In SSRS report, I'm getting datetime format mm/dd/yyyy. I want to change it to dd/mm/yyyy.

I have added expression like:

```
=FormatDateTime(Format(Fields!TransactionDate.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy"),DateFormat.ShortDate)
```

But, this is showing #Error in the report.
How to correct this?

Comment: Is the underlying data type string or datetime?

Answer (score 24):

If the field in the data set is datetime, then the expression to use is

```
=FORMAT(Fields!Dataset_Field_Name_Here.Value,"dd/MM/yyyy")
```

From looking at the expression, the 'DateFormat.ShortDate' is using the language set for the report?  Goto report -> properties -> Localization -> Language.  I set it to en-GB so that it will display dates in the format l require. However this value if l remember correctly can be overridden by the language settings on the client computer displaying the report.

[image: Report Properties showing Localization -> Language]

Answer (score 12):

Got solution:

```
 =CDate(Fields!TransactionDate.Value).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")
```

Answer (score 9):

Go to textbox properties: Before changing the Custom to dd/MM/yyyy (as shown), select option Date and select format MM/dd/yyyy i.e. 01/31/2000 in RS 2008. Hope it helps.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Format(Cdate(Fields!TransactionDate.Value),"dd/MM/yyyy")